# What is the relation between Chebyshev polynomials and coupled oscillators?

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes, special-functions

I have been told that Chebyshev polynomials are key for finding the normal modes of oscillations of a linear chain of coupled oscillators, since they are the eigenmodes of the system. However, I cannot see why is the case nor can I find any textbook that solves the problem this way. Does somebody know any textbook or article that covers it?

Comment: Why don't you tell us exactly what you mean by a "chain of coupled oscillators."?  I can think of several systems that might  be described as such.

Comment: By chain of linear oscillators, I mean a system of N particles of identical mass, labelled 1,2,...N where particle i is connected to particles i-1 and i+1 by springs with identical elastic constant. Particle 1 is connected only to particle 2 (there is no wall nor periodic boundary conditions) and particle N is only connected to particle N-1.

Comment: I think the [roots of the Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema) are related to the eigenfrequencies of the system you're describing. It seems likely that's not a coincidence, but I don't know a method to use this property of the Chebyshev polynomials to derive the eigenfrequencies. You don't *need* to use Chebyshev polynomials to derive these modes, anyway; what I would consider a more standard method would just be to directly diagonalize the equations of motion. Maybe the Chebyshev polynomials let you diagonalize in an elegant way.

Comment: [Vourdas 2001](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00682-8).

Comment: There is a beautiful result evaluating the powers of a 2-by-2 matrix by evaluating Chebyshev polynomials whose arguments are functions of the trace and determinant of a matrix.  [See Theorem 1 here](https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/symmetry/symmetry-12-00746/article_deploy/symmetry-12-00746.pdf?version=1588745713). This result is used to evaluate powers of the transfer matrix for waves traveling in periodic systems (whether optical or quantum mechanical). That would be related here, and so it is likely what's going on.